# greatest common factor function

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to solve this challenge problem, where I am meant to find the GCD of two inputted numbers by referencing a function. However, I am not sure exactly where I am messing up. Here is the exact question for reference:

Write a function which accepts x and y as input parameters and calculates and returns the greatest common denominator of both values.

I tried making a function to find the GCD, and then just referencing the function later. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int gcd;

cout << "Enter a valid integer: ";
  cin >> n >> m;

int digit = number(n, m);



return 0;
}

int number(int n, int m){

  for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i){
    int gcd = i;
    if(n%i==0 && m%i==0) {
      break;
  }

    return gcd;
}
  }
```

I should be getting this: 
Enter two integers: 12 8
The GCD of 12 and 8 is 4.

But instead, I'm getting an error with gcd not being declared in this scope, which doesn't make sense because I declared it as an int both inside the function and outside.

Comment: What are you hoping the line `return gcd(n, m);` would do?

Comment: That was a mistake, I just realized; I want to just print the gcd in this case of the two numbers, which would be represented by i.

Comment: @RSahu after taking out the error in the return line and just making it become return gcd; , I still get the error that gcd is not declared.

Comment: That error makes sense. `gcd` is defined in the scope of the `if` statement. It doesn't exist outside that.

Comment: Remember that curly braces introduce a new scope. Also, the `gcd` in `main` is completely unrelated to the `gcd` in the other function. Read about lexical scope in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: Once you get that to compile and return a value, you will have found the *smallest* common divisor, which is 1.

Comment: @molbdnilo ive updated the code, but what do I do to fix this? I'm confused.

Comment: What happened to the non-recursive criteria - it was in the title but then it got removed?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you are looking for something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hcf(int, int); //function declaration 

int main()
{
int a, b, result;

printf(“Enter the two numbers to find their HCF: “);
scanf(“%d%d”, &a, &b);
result = hcf(a, b);
printf(“The HCF of %d and %d is %d.\n”, a, b, result);

return 0;
}

int hcf(int a, int b)
{
            while (a != b)
            {
                  if (a > b)
                 {
                            a = a – b;
                  }
           else
                    {
                         b = b – a;
                   }
}
return a;
}
```

Simple program which is easy to understand .

Answer (score 1):

There are pretty good recursive algorithms for this, but since they're not allowed, I cleaned up your implementation:

- Replace faulty iomanip for iostream
- Change your input prompt from "Enter an integer" to "Enter two integers"
- Removed i from your main, you didn't need it
- Replaced variable with gcd in your main
- Added a cout to show the result in your main
- With your gcdfunction I rewrote it keeping only your break condition
- The loop to match your break condition must be a count down starting from an appropriate number (i.e. min(m, n) should be the initial value and we loop backwards until we hit 1).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int gcdfunction(int n, int m);

int main() {
  int n, m;

  cout << "Enter two integers: ";
  cin >> n >> m;

  int gcd = gcdfunction(n, m);
  cout << "GCD: " << gcd << "\n";
  return 0;
}

int gcdfunction(int n, int m){
  for (int i = m<=n ? m:n ; i > 1; i--) {
    if (n%i==0 && m%i==0) return i;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy recursive solution...try this.

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b==0)
       return a;
    else
       gcd(b, a%b);
}
```

Same can be achieved without recursion -

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
     while(b!=0)
     {
         int tmp = a;
         a = b;
         b = tmp % b;
     {
     return a;
 }
```

Now the main function ..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int a,b;
   cout<<"Enter two number: ";
   cin>>a>>b;
   cout<<"GCD of two number: "<<gcd(a,b)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `int gcd(int x, int y){return y? gcd(y,x%y) : x;}` will work too

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs a little bit of tweaking to work correctly.

1. `gcd` has to be defined outside the `for` loop so it can be used as the return value.
2. In the `for` loop, using `break` in the `if` statement is logically incorrect. If you do that, you will always get 1 as your answer. Afer all, `n % 1` and `m % 1` will be zero for all values of `n` and `m`.

Here's an updated version that works in my tests.

```
int gcdfunction(int n, int m){

   int gcd = 1;
   for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i){
      if(n%i==0 && m%i==0) {
         gcd = i;
      }
   }

   return gcd;
}
```

Please note that [the Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is probably the most efficient algorithm to compute the GCD of two numbers.

The Euclidean algorithm can be easily implemented using a non-recursive function too.

```
int gcdfunction(int n, int m){

   // Make sure n is the smaller of the numbers.
   if ( n > m )
   {
      std::swap(n, m);
   }

   while ( m % n != 0 )
   {
      int next = m % n;
      m = n;
      n = next;
   }

   return n;
}
```

Comment: I did a cout command, being cout << gcd; , and I get the factors of my two numbers perfectly. However, all values of i that fullfill the loop are being printed; how do I only get the highest value to get printed? If I put 12 and 20, the numbers outputted are 1, 2, and 4.

Comment: @noviceclasscoder, print only the return value of the function, in `main`. After the function returns, use `std::cout << "GCD: " << variable << std::endl;`